# Access eclipse variables outside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am working on an ant scrip that can be located in one place, but can be targeted to run on each project. I am able to do this in eclipse using the ${project_loc} variable in eclipse. I was also able to get this variable to work in ant, by setting it as a variable to through the eclipse preferences. This works fine, but it only works in eclipse. Is there any way that I could get the path to a specific project through a script so that I could run my ant script outside of eclipse?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#passing-cli-args

ant -Dname=value

Comment: But the variable I want is a project location in eclipse ${project_loc}. So that solves half of the problem, but I still need to access the eclipse variable. Thanks though